# Difference between vim’s normal-mode S and cc commands?

Tags: vim

Is there a difference between the vim normal-mode commands `S` and `cc`?

In my use cases, both commands seem to delete the current line and move into insertion mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the `vim` help documentation (section 04.2  Changing text) there is no difference:

```
S  stands for  cc  (change a whole line)
```

Answer (score 2):

One is a synonym for the other. See `:help S`:

> *S*
> ["x]S      Delete [count] lines [into register x] and start
>                         insert.  Synonym for "cc" |linewise|.